# Convert ctime() to Time::tm

Tags: perl, datetime, timestamp, ctime

I have a perl method that is using Time::tm values and I'd like to compare a file time.  Using File::stat to get the file ctime (`ctime(stat($file)->mtime)`) returns a scalar value that is a human-readable format.  Is there a way to return or convert this to a Time::tm format?

Answer (score 0):

use the member function:

time_t CTime::GetTime( ) const; // Returns a time_t value for the given CTime object.

[example](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?159142-convert-CTime-varianble-into-time_t)

Comment: I'm not familiar with member functions so will have to do some investigation.  Thanks.